# Select from a knockout given element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

EDIT:
I solved my actual issue by binding directly onto the elements that need the changes, thus removing the need to do any selection. So I am fine now. If however somebody can teach me what was wrong in the first place, I'll still be happy to see an answer :)

I am trying apply a .collapsible({refresh: true}) on all elements that match the selector div[data-role='collapsible'] on an element that is given to me in a self written knockout binding.

However I fail to select the divs I want. In fact all selectors I've tried (like "div" either find nothing or just return the input element:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.refreshCollapsible = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(function() {
            // this prints [1]
            console.log(element);
            // this prints [2]
            console.log($(element));
            // these find nothing, see [3]
            console.log($(element).filter("div[data-role='collapsible']"));
            console.log($(element).find("div[data-role='collapsible']"));
            console.log($("div[data-role='collapsible']", element));
            // this one seems to return the same as $(element)
            console.log($(element, "div[data-role='collapsible']"));
    });}
```

[1]
[image: example 1]

[2]
[image: example 2]

[3]
[image: example 3]

What am I doing wrong? I've searched around quite a bit for "hot to select things from a given note" and found the methods I am trying, but none work. I am completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing these console.log's aren't done in the `$(document).ready()` function?

Knockout applies the `foreach` binding and then the `<div>` are only created once the document is ready, so only then can they be seen on the DOM by jQuery.

So try (if it's not like this already):

```
$(function() {
    // this prints [1]
 console.log(element);
     // this prints [2]
 console.log($(element));
 // these find nothing, see [3]
 console.log($(element).filter("div[data-role='collapsible']"));
 console.log($(element).find("div[data-role='collapsible']"));
 console.log($("div[data-role='collapsible']", element));
 // this one seems to return the same as $(element)
 console.log($(element, "div[data-role='collapsible']"));
});
```

Comment: I indeed did not have an onReady. I added it, see OP. No changes though. I am not quite sure I understand why it would matter though, element is given to me by knockout. I am assuming it is a ready to use element that I can do selections on?

Comment: It's likely that jQuery Mobile is moving elements in and out of the DOM, so the element you bound to may not actually be in the DOM at the time of the update.